# simple diving question in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So the Discrete Math exam is on friday and i am still very confused with which formula should i was in cases that looks very simillar, there are these 4 question :

a) Divide 30 students to 6 different classes. 
b) Divide 30 students to 6 simillar classes. 
c) Divide 30 oranges to 6 different boxes. 
 
d) Divide 30 oranges to 6 simillar boxes.

I can't seem to figure out when there are repeats and when the order is importent in these cases and how i solve each question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we read "different" as "distinguishable" and "similar" as "indistinguishable", we might also assume that the students are distinguishable and the oranges are not.

There's also a possible reading that has "similar classes" meaning all the same size, which is a different problem, and there is perhaps an implicit expectation that classes will not be empty. I'll leave those for the time being.

So without the above constraints:

- (a) Each student can be allocated freely to a class. So each one has 6 choices, 30 students, it's a straight $6^{30}$.
- (a') Forbidding empty classes just leaves some possibilities to remove from the above, $6\cdot5^{30}$, which leaves some (with two empty classes) to add back in, $15\cdot 4^{30}$, which leaves (with three) some to take out again, $20\cdot 3^{30}$, then a few more to put back, $15\cdot 2^{30}$, and a final few to take out, $6\cdot 1^{30}$. A bit messy.
- (a'') Requiring same-sized classes means a different approach is easier - consider permutations of the students, $30!$, then divide in blocks of 5. Each possible set of 5 student in each class has been count $5!$ times, though, so the solution is $\frac{30!}{5!5!5!5!5!5!}$
- (b) Each student can be allocated freely as in (a), but when we are done, we have multiple-counted situations where the classes are shuffled. This multiple-counting is complicated by the fact that some classes may be identically-sized in some of the solutions and not in others.
- (b') Reading "similar classes" as "same-sized, indistinguishable groups", the problem is easier again. We can allocate the students as per (a'') then divide by the class shuffle, $6!$.
- (c)  This is a straight stars&bars division, ${35\choose 5}$
- (d) Again this is more complex; the partitions of 30 are captured by the Stirling number of the second kind which we have to adjust slightly to allow empty boxes, ${36}\brace{6}$